# Randomise quiz questions from xml file with javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, random

I just created a quiz in a xml file. I manage to make the hole code work properly. I'm now stuck at one point, how to make the quiz questions appear random? Bellow you can see one of the question in Javascript.

```js
<!-- question 1 -->
        <question id="q1" time="15" event="">

    <box id="col1" position="relative" class="col-md-6" />
    <box id="col2" position="relative" class="col-md-6" />

    <text id="question1" position="relative" target="col1" x="0" margin-top="150" margin-bottom="40" anim="left" animtime="0.5"><![CDATA[<p class="p_24">What's my name?</p>]]></text>
    <image id="fb1image" position="relative" target="col1" x="0" y="0" margin-bottom="30" anim="none" class="img-responsive"><![CDATA[lib/assets/c1.jpg]]></image>
<!--option 1 -->
<option correct="true">
<text id="option1_1" position="relative" target="col1" x="match" width="100%" margin-bottom="5" anim="left" animtime="0.5" animdelay="0.5" event="optionover,selectandsubmit" class="optionBox"><![CDATA[<p class="p_16 white">Pontus</p>]]></text>
</option>
<!--option 2 -->
<option correct="false">
<text id="option1_2" position="relative" target="col1" x="match" width="100%" margin-bottom="5" anim="left" animtime="0.5" animdelay="0.6" event="optionover,selectandsubmit" class="optionBox"><![CDATA[<p class="p_16 white">Peter/Bb</p>]]></text>
</option>
<!--/options -->
<!-- feedbacks -->
<fb id="pass" event="">

<box id="fb" position="relative" target="col2" margin-top="150" clear="both" anim="show" animtime="0.5">
<image id="passimage" position="relative" x="0" y="0" margin-bottom="30" anim="none" class="img-responsive"><![CDATA[lib/assets/c1_correct.jpg]]></image>

<text id="txt1" position="relative" anim="none" margin-bottom="30"><![CDATA[<p class="p_24">Correct!</p><p>My name is Pontus.</p><p>Good job!</p>]]></text>
<button id="nextQBtn" position="relative" width="150" margin-bottom="10" anim="none" event="btnover,loadNextQuestion"><![CDATA[Next]]></button>

<text id="bottompad" position="relative" anim="none"><![CDATA[<p>&nbsp;</p>]]></text>
</box>
</fb>
<fb id="fail" event="">
<box id="fb" position="relative" target="col2" margin-top="150" clear="both" anim="show" animtime="0.5">
<image id="failimage" position="relative" x="0" y="0" margin-bottom="30" anim="none" class="img-responsive"><![CDATA[lib/assets/c1_correct.jpg]]></image>

<text id="txt1" position="relative" anim="none" margin-bottom="30"><![CDATA[<p class="p_24">Wrong!</p><p>My name is Pontus.</p><p>Be careful!</p>]]></text>
<button id="nextQBtn" position="relative" width="150" margin-bottom="10" anim="none" event="btnover,loadNextQuestion"><![CDATA[Next]]></button>

<text id="bottompad" position="relative" anim="none"><![CDATA[<p>&nbsp;</p>]]></text>
</box>
</fb>
</question>
```

Comment: I assume your XML file contains the whole question database. So the simplest approach would be to transfer all your questions to an array - let's call it `questions`, and generate a random number `x` in the range of 0 to `questions.length - 1`. Use that number to retrieve your random question from the array: `questions[x]`. If you want to avoid that questions randomly repeat you need to shuffle your whole `questions` array. Look up the "Knuth-Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm" for doing that properly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I want the questions to be random and doesn't matter if they repeat. Could you please guide me through Skype? or Facebook?